# php - diffing nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, diff

I have 2 multidimensional arrays:

```
$first_array = array(
  0 => array(tid => 141), 
  1 => array(tid => 142), 
  2 => array(tid => 128)
);

$second_array = array(
  0 => array(tid => 141), 
  1 => array(tid => 128)
);
```

I need to check if there are any items in the second array that are present in the first array.  If there are, I need to remove them from the first array.

Taking the example above, `$first_array` should end up as `array(0 => array(tid => 142))`

Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is what I used:

```
$first_array = array(
  0 => array('tid' => 141), 
  1 => array('tid' => 142), 
  2 => array('tid' => 128)
);

$second_array = array(
  0 => array('tid' => 141), 
  1 => array('tid' => 128)
);


function my_serialize(&$arr,$pos){ 
  $arr = serialize($arr); 
} 

function my_unserialize(&$arr,$pos){ 
  $arr = unserialize($arr); 
} 

 //make a copy 
$first_array_s = $first_array; 
$second_array_s = $second_array; 

// serialize all sub-arrays 
array_walk($first_array_s,'my_serialize'); 
array_walk($second_array_s,'my_serialize'); 

// array_diff the serialized versions 
$diff = array_diff($first_array_s,$second_array_s); 

// unserialize the result 
array_walk($diff,'my_unserialize'); 

print_r($diff);
```

Comment: The efficient way to do this is sort them by tid [O(logN)+O(logK)] and compare them in a foreach. [O(max(N,K))]

Comment: Check the comments on http://php.net/manual/function.array-diff.php there are several helper functions...

Comment: Sweet!   I was able to use an example that serializes and unserializes the arrays and uses array_diff.  Thank you powtac!